# AcquireTokenForUser in ASP.NET Core Web app

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-6.0, azure-ad-msal, msal

I have a AspNetCore app in net6.0.
The user is asked to login against Azure Ad (Entra).

After this is done, the web app needs to make a call to an API. The endpoint it hits has a scope requirement. This is a scope the web app registration has permission for in Azure.

How do I get a hold of a token containing that scope, so I can use it to authorize in the API? I've looked at `_tokenAcquisition.AcquireTokenForUser`, but even if I have all AzureAd configuration in pla, including a client secret, it says `no account or login hint was passed to AcquireTokenSilent`.

Reading the documentation confuses me, and it's hard to find a concrete example of what I'm after.
I've tried different solutions in code, but none seem to work.

Any help appreciated, and let me know if more info is needed, thanks!

Comment: .net 6 and .net 8 has the same  configuration and codes, the only difference might be the nuget package version. Anyway you can create a new .net 6 web app and choose "Microsoft Identity Platform" for Authentication type, you would found there's some configurations in appsettings.json, related authentication service in Program.cs, and then there will be a _LoginPartial view added, and this partial view will be used in _Layout.cshtml

Comment: I found a sample here which containing detailed steps: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/3-WebApp-multi-APIs/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, we can only say that you didn't sign in successfully so that the `_tokenAcquisition` failed to work. Since you didn't share how you compose your code, pls allow me to share my steps.

Firstly, I created a new .net 8 mvc application, when creating the app, I choose "Microsoft Identity Platform" as the authentication type. Then I need to modify the appsettings.json, Program.cs and HomeController.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "aad_client_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

In Program.cs, add toke acquisition service, and http service to send http request.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

Then inject related service to generate access token and send http request.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        _logger = logger;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://client_id_exposing_API/Tiny.Read" });

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:7076/home/getData")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer "+ accessToken}
            }
        };

        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string getData() {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Just like you see, after I sign in the app and hit the action method, I can generate access token successfully which containing correct scope I set in my method.

[image]

Nuget packages I used are generated by VS 2022 template:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.15.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try this later today. Do you know if the scope permission needs to be admin consented in order for this to work?

Comment: That's based on the scope itself, when we expose an API permission, we can check in the "API permissions" page to see whether the required scope is `Admin consent required`. If "yes", then we need to grant admin consent, if not, when the first time we sign in our web app, it would appear a window to show you that this app require some consent.

Comment: Thank you for the info - I changed the configuration and code to the example you gave me, and received the same 'login hint or account missing' error. Turns out, I just had to refresh my login (tested via incognito mode). Worked like a charm. Access token received, with scope included. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply and I'm glad to see your issue solved : )